# Flask - POST Request is sending partial input values

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm currently making a little game with Python/Flask and some Javascript but when I submit my form I can only receive some values but others are None existing :

So here is my form :

```
<form name="question_form" id="question_form" action="{{ url_for('question') }} " method='POST' onsubmit="return validateAnswer()">
            <p class="question">{{ question }}</p>
            <button name="given_answerA" type="submit" class="clickable" id="questions_A" value="{{ answers[0] }}">{{ answers[0] }}</button>
            <button name="given_answerB" type="submit" class="clickable" id="questions_B" value="{{ answers[1] }}">{{ answers[1] }}</button>
            <button name="given_answerC" type="submit" class="clickable" id="questions_C" value="{{ answers[2] }}">{{ answers[2] }}</button>
            <button name="given_answerD" type="submit" class="clickable" id="questions_D" value="{{ answers[3] }}">{{ answers[3] }}</button>
            <input name="nb_question" id="nb_question" type="hidden" value="{{ nb }}"/>
            <input name="choice_good" id="choice_good" type="hidden" value="{{ choice_good }}"/>
        </form>
```

In my flask APP here is what I do :

```
answered = request.form.get('given_answerA')
correct_answer = request.form.get('choice_good')
nb_question = int(request.form.get('nb_question')
```

I have a result for "correct_answer" and "nb_question" but given_answerA is not existing, I tried to print request.form to see the content and I only see the values of choice_good and nb_question.

I tried to rename all my button with same name, changing to "button type=submit" "input type=submit" but seems that none of them works ..

Any ideas ? Thanks !

EDIT : It seems that the JS function (that I forgot to include is the problem) here it is :

```
function validateAnswer() {
    var answered = document.activeElement.id;
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio_validate");
    var form = document.getElementById("question_form");
    var background_audio = document.getElementById("background_audio");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var filename = 'static/images/background_' + answered + ".jpg";
    body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+filename+')';
    background_audio.pause();
    audio.play();
    setTimeout(function(){
        form.submit();
    }, 20000);
        return false;
```

If I keep return false, the buttons are empty (so I think it submit with JS without knowing that the button was clicked)
If i keep return true, the timeout is not executed and also no music is paused and play but the post value are sent; I need this "20" sec delay to play the music correctly and to make suspens as it is a who wants to be a millionaire game

Comment: I looked directly in "Network" on my web browser and only the two last values are sent

Comment: Does `validateAnswer` mess something up?

Comment: The form works for me, but I removed `validateAnswer`, since you didn't post that function.

Comment: I edited my question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS function intercepts the submit event (which contains data on which of the buttons was clicked) and calls `form.submit` manually, that's why the button value doesn't get sent.

A simple way to fix this would be to add another hidden field which you would set to the value of the button that was pressed from your JS function.

Comment: What an odd ! I asked my problem to a friend and he just replied a similar solution like yours, you are right !! here is what I did :
`var answered = document.activeElement.value;`
`document.getElementById('given_answer').value = answered;`
Conclusion : The form don't know which button is clicked when we override the submit function, so yeah adding a hidden input and then setting its value makes the trick :) thanks !!

Comment: Yeah, stuff like this can be very confusing :) You're welcome!